# How to use $ http and $ compile on this Json

Tags: angularjs, json

I wrote this jquery on onclick.I want Json to do this, but I can not compile the code.

This is the result of my efforts:

```
function PostEndid (y) {
    var getcityid=$(y).attr('data-id');
    $(".EndCityID").attr("value", getcityid);
     $http({
       url: 'test-js.bc',
       type: 'post', 
       data : {
        StartCityID: $(".StartCityID").val(),
        EndCityID : $(".EndCityID").val(),
       },
      success:function(response){ $(y).closest("tr").find(".airlinename").empty().html($compile(response))(scope); }
     });
```

Comment: Please elaborate what part you are stuck at? You have provided fraction of code which make unclear what is exact problem. It will be better if you write Fiddle for your code.

Comment: Why are you getting values using jQuery? please take a look at [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). Also not clear what your problem is.